# End Match if Home Button is Pressed

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

How would I end a match/disconnect the opposing player and/or remove the match maker standard interface (GameKit), if the Home button on the device is pressed? I also have a "Main Menu" button on screen and if that is pressed, I would like to end the match/disconnect the opposing player. I'm using GameKit to find and start matches.

I am new to multiplayer so any help is appreciated.

```
-(void) match:(GKMatch*)match player:(NSString*)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case GKPlayerStateConnected:
            [delegate onPlayerConnected:playerID];
            break;
        case GKPlayerStateDisconnected:
            CCLOG(@"Disconnected");
            [delegate onPlayerDisconnected:playerID];
            break;
    }

    if (matchStarted == NO && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
    {
        matchStarted = YES;
        [delegate onStartMatch];
    }
}


-(void) disconnectCurrentMatch
{
    CCLOG(@"Quit Match");
    [currentMatch disconnect];
    currentMatch.delegate = nil;
    [currentMatch release];
    currentMatch = nil;
}
```

That is all I am using to disconnect players. Then when the player presses the "Main Menu" button this is the code.

```
-(void)Menu: (id) sender
{
    didQuit = YES;

    if (isSingle == YES)
    {
        GameKitHelper* gkHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];
        [gkHelper disconnectCurrentMatch];
        gkHelper.delegate = nil;
    }

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [MainMenu scene]];
    CCLOG(@"Return Main Menu");
}
```

It replaces the scene to the Main Menu, but never changes the state to disconnected.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the (isSingle == YES) code to make sure that logic is being executed?

Comment: If you mean "break;" I can't being it is not in a loop or switch, but I did add a "CCLOG" to check and yes it was being called. I also added another check within the "disconnectCurrentMatch" and when I press the main menu button in game is calls it.

Comment: hmm.. how do you know that it is not disconnected? When you change scene it auto disconnects? NO?

Comment: No, I meant an Xcode breakpoint -- stopping the execution at that point and checking what's going on.  But if you know for sure that isSingle == YES then it's fine. that's what I wanted to confirm.  What's in this method: [delegate onPlayerDisconnected:playerID];

Comment: Just "CCLOG(@"onPlayerDisconnected: %@", playerID);" to tell which player has disconnected. What I have found out is that the state doesn't change unless I tap the main menu button then go back to start another match.  Then the "onPlayerDisconnected" is called and the "onPlayerConnected" is called once again. I am also using the simulator and my device to test multiplayer.

Comment: @makdad - I'm going to buy an iPhone this weekend to test multiplayer/Gamekit/Game Center on two ACTUAL devices so I can let you know if any of this worked on Friday. If you have any more suggestions feel free to post them.

Comment: @Jon, I'd suspect that may have something to do with it.  Have you tested both ways (e.g. debugging the phone, debugging the simulator)?  Is it possible it only works as expected on one side?

Comment: I have tested both ways running CCLogs if that's what you mean by debugging(I am still a beginner so please work with me) but, if you mean break points no I have yet to do that. Also, it is VERY possible that it is only working as expected on the iPod due to the limited usage of the simulator. I am hoping once I have the application running on two actual devices(and press the main menu button) that the match will end and "clean up" the screen(for the other player). I am also trying to implement sending data(just the opponents score), but that is another story... and again, thank you so much

Comment: One more thing, I have been reading some of Apple's documents on match making. It says that when a player disconnects from the match your application should notify the delegate about the disconnection and "disconnectCurrentMatch" notifies the delegate with "[currentMatch disconnect];
" and as you can see in my "MainMenu" method I have add the "[currentMatch disconnect];" so hopefully that will solve my problem on actual devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon,

When the home button is pressed, your application delegate will receive the `-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application` callback.

You have roughly 5 seconds (before Springboard kills your app) to do whatever you need to do to clean up your app (unless you need more time, which you can request from iOS, but aren't guaranteed to receive).

How do you "clean up"?  As you mentioned - your match has 2 players, so either player disconnecting or quitting has the same effect on the game - ending it (assuming that a player cannot continue to play on by him/herself).

Your leaving player will send a `-disconnect` message to GameKit.

The player left behind's program needs to have an object that conforms to the [GKMatchDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKMatchDelegate/match%3adidReceiveData%3afromPlayer%3a) protocol and receives callbacks as the delegate of `GKMatch`.

When an opposing player disconnects, GKMatch will call to the delegate with:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state`
```

So, now your player that has been left behind's code will have also been notified.  In that method, check if it's disconnection - and if so, follow your own logic for what you want to happen when a player is "hung up on".

Comment: I'm using Cocos2d, so when the home button is pressed it automatically pauses the game. So, I added in a BOOL to check if it was in Multiplayer (isMP = YES when the scene is replaced to multiplayer & isMP = NO when the scene is replaced to Single player).  In applicationWillTerminate and applicationDidEnterBackground I added a check "if (isMP == YES) { //cancel match }" but I can't find out what to put in between those brackets to cancel the match and/or remove the standard match maker interface. I can't seem to find it in the API docs either. I know it's probably just one line of code.

Comment: Not sure of the use case, but isn't this what you want: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKMatch/disconnect ?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't disconnect the player nor notify the opposing player that they were disconnected, I'm stumped.

Comment: It's not your responsibility when disconnecting to notify the opposing player -- it's the opposing player's implementation that is supposed to via the delegate callback they will receive upon your disconnection.

Comment: Jon - forgot one important thing.  In your game, can only 2 people play?

Comment: yes it's only 2 players and really the only part that is multiplayer is I need the opponents score to show on the player's screen and I can't figure that out either.

Comment: So is this issue resolved, or you still need help?  Ask another question for the other issue!

Comment: It's not I still need the original question answered

Comment: I just looked at your edited answer and I have tried that so many times. I put if (didQuit == YES) { matchStarted = NO; [delegate matchEnded]; } but it never gets called. I just don't get it...

Comment: Jon, can you post your "match closing" code for both the one who is closing and the one who is being closed upon?  (ie both players)

Comment: I added it to my original question

Comment: GameKit is iOS 4.1+ so the iOS 3.0 behavior is irrelevant. You can also perform more code if you start a background task.

Comment: @jon, how'd you go with the device?

Comment: I have to wait until next week before I can test on two devices. I will post back here if it works

Comment: @makdad, I just bought the new iPhone 4 and tested it with my iPod Touch 4G and it didn't work...